# Asp.Net with C# textbox value 0

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I am using the following code to try to set the Textbox value as 0 when textbox1.text ="".

```
if(textbox1.text=="")
{
     int.Parse(textbox1.Text) == 0.ToString();
}
```

However I recieve the following error:

`Error: CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.`

How do I set the textbox value to 0 in C#?

Answer (score 4):

A simple assignment operator should do the job. You really don't need to do any parsing and equality comparison operator:

```
if(textbox1.Text == "")
{
    textbox1.Text = "0";
}
```

Comment: This error must be somewhere else. In a portion of the code that you haven't shown.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for your problem**

```
if (string.IsNullorEmpty(textbox1.Text))
{
    textbox1.Text = "0";
}
```

**Reasons for your problem**

1. `int.Parse` returns an integer and you are trying to compare string to int.
2. `==` operator is used to check whether left hand side is equal to right hand side, which you are trying to use as an assignment operator.

Comment: +1 for NullOrEmpty - No idea why someone downvoted this, it looks to be a good answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

you are parsing the value of the `TextBox` to integer ,but you don't want to do that ,you want to set it's value, so simply use the setter property

```
yourTextBox.Text="0";
```

and then you are setting it wrong using the conditional == instead of the assignment =

```
== is used to check if two things are equal ex: 1==1
```

you should use this `=` to assign or set

Answer (score 0):

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text))
{
     textbox1.Text = "0";
}
```

`IsNullOrEmpty` wud check for null values also.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things wrong with the code.

`int.Parse` if its able to parse will give a `int` value while you have set up a comparison of the same with a `string`.

Next you can use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` to check if the `TextBox` is empty or not.

Finally you can just assign `"0"` as string to the `.Text` property of the `TextBox`

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox1.Text))
{
     textbox1.Text = "0";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this:

```
if(textbox1.Text == "")
{
    textbox1.Text = "0";
}
```